# Group by and aggregate by multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Example tables

**taccount**

[image]

**tuser**

[image]

**tproject**

[image]

What I want to achieve:

```
accountName count(u.id) count(p.id)
-----------------------------------
Account A   1           1
Account B   1           1
Account C   2           3
```

In other words I want a single query to join these tables together and count user's and project's per account

I tried:

```
SELECT
    a.name as "accountName",
    count(u.name),
    count(p.id)
FROM "taccount" a
INNER JOIN "tuser" u ON u.account_id = a.id
INNER JOIN "tproject" p ON p.admin_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.name, a.name, p.id
```

But it's not grouping by account. It's giving me the following result

[image]

Any advice?

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions. E.g try  `GROUP BY u.name`.

Comment: give tables ...........

Comment: Most people here want sample table data as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: give them as texts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below

```
SELECT
    a.name as "accountName",
    count(distinct u.name),
    count(p.id)
FROM "taccount" a
INNER JOIN "tuser" u ON u.account_id = a.id
INNER JOIN "tproject" p ON p.admin_id = u.id
GROUP BY  a.name
```

Comment: Thanks, that distinct was needed indeed. Can't accept as answer yet, still have to wait a few mins.

Comment: @Jim-Y, yes without distinct you'll not get proper count for u.name

Answer (score 1):

change your group by column name

```
SELECT
    a.name as "accountName",
    count(distinct u.account_id),
    count(p.id)
FROM "taccount" a
INNER JOIN "tuser" u ON u.account_id = a.id
INNER JOIN "tproject" p ON p.admin_id = u.id
GROUP BY  a.name
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `Aggregate` Function and If there are Column are not do `Aggregate` you must put in your `Group By`, because `Aggregate` functions perform a calculation on a set of rows and return a single row.

```
SELECT
   a.name as "accountName",
   count(distinct u.name),
   count(p.id)
FROM 
   "taccount" a
   INNER JOIN "tuser" u ON u.account_id = a.id
   INNER JOIN "tproject" p ON p.admin_id = u.id
GROUP BY  
   a.name
```

So you need just `Group By` your column `"accountName"`

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select a.name,count(u.id),count(p.id) from 
taccount a,tuser b, tproject where
a.id=b.account_id and
b.id=c.admin_id
group by a.name;
```

Comment: Yes.. It will work.. But you are doing `implicit join`.. And the community are not support this `join`

Comment: @dwir182 it will work can i ask whats wrong with it??

Comment: Even `postgresql` see this as same semantic.. But community are not support this type.. :)